# jeditable textbox width

Tags: jquery, jeditable

is there anyway to make the textbox bigger than the text when using inline replace with jeditable.  I want to give the user room to add new text on top of the existing text.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can specify `height` and `width` in settings to set the textbox to specific height and width. <strike>There is also a function callback `onedit` which you can hookup to set specific size of edit box</strike> *this did not work*.

```
<span id="edit">hello world!</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("span#edit").editable("....",
 {
            event: "click",
            style: "inherit",
            onblur: "submit",
            width:($("span#edit").width() + 200) + "px", // THIS DOES THE TRICK
            height:($("span#edit").height() + 100) + "px", //THIS DOES THE TRICK
            placeholder: "Click to set text",
            tooltip: "Click to update"
        });
   });
</script>
```